# Explode string and make a line break after each word

Tags: javascript, split

I have a textbox (I usually call it like this: `document.forms[0].text.value`)
that has this kind of value:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,etc
```

what I want to do is "explode" (like the php function) on each of the commas in the above string, then put it back into the textbox so I end up with this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
etc
```

Doing a little Googling I see I will need to use `split()` but doing something like:

```
st.split(",") + "<br />";
```

is giving me nothing but invalid results.

Comment: Try using var newStr = str.replace(",", "\n");

Comment: @SOliver - why don't you post that as an answer instead?

Comment: It's a single line of code. I figured I'd be as well putting it here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either:

```
st.split(",").join("\n");
```

or:

```
st.replace(/,/g,"\n");
```

Since you're putting it in a textarea, by the look of things, you need newlines, not BR tags.

Comment: Thanks guys! Gah! The irritating part is..I was sooo close! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are right in saying that

```
st.split(",")
```

will split `st` into an array of the substrings you are looking for.  However, you want to put each substring onto its own line, not one line for all the substrings.  So, you need

```
st.split(",").join("<br />")
```

to place a `br` tag in between each of the substrings and thus put each on its own line.

Answer (score -2):

```
    var string = "University of USA";
    string =  string.split('').join('<br>');
```